# error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:783: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting an error.

Here is my code on which I am stuck:

```
for label in labels:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print('Collecting images for {}'.format(label))
    time.sleep(5)
    for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
        print('Collecting image {}'.format(imgnum))
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH,label,label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
        cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        time.sleep(2)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I should have got was:
Collecting images for thumbsup
Collecting image 0
Collecting image 1
Collecting image 2
Collecting image 3
Collecting image 4

Comment: `cap.read()` returned an empty image.  It does that sometimes.  You need to check for that condition before calling `imwrite()`.

Comment: If only someone asked about this problem before.... [oh, wait](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%21_img.empty%28%29+in+function+%27imwrite%27)

Answer (score -1):

Try this. You can write your own `dir_path`.

When executing the script, every time you press 'c' to save it.

Snippet:

```
import cv2
import os


def save_still_sequence_key(device_num, dir_path, basename, ext='jpg', delay=1, window_title='still frame sequence'):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device_num)

    if not cap.isOpened():
        return
    
    os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)
    base_path = os.path.join(dir_path, basename)

    n = 0
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow(window_title, frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(delay) 
        if key == ord('c'):
            cv2.imwrite(f'{base_path}_{n}.{ext}', frame)
            n += 1
        elif key == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.destroyWindow(window_name)


save_still_sequence_key(0, 'data/temp', 'still_frame_sequence')
```